# How to monitor the Network usage of a particular interface in Java?

Tags: java, networking, monitoring

I want to know the exact amount of data which is getting transferred through a particular network interface for logging purpose, is there any standard library or api call from which I can do this in a cross platfrom way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SNMP4J](http://www.snmp4j.org/) will let you read the [interface mib](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2020.html) of any SNMP-compliant device. Linux and OSX (probably) have an SNMP daemon already running; Windows has an [SNMP service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379100(VS.85).aspx) that you can [install though Programs and Features in Control Panel](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/11/01/install-and-enable-snmp-service-in-windows-xp-vista-and-2003/).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do what you'd like. At least, I think it will point you in the right direction:
http://jnetpcap.com/

edit: While not strictly cross-platform, libpcap has libraries for all major platforms so I wouldn't consider that a show-stopper, but I'm not the one that needs it.

Comment: Note that this library relies on native code accessed via JNI. There is no cross-platform way to do what you're trying to do. Java might not be the best fit.

Answer (score 1):

jNetPcap uses [Sigar](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) in some of its unit tests. Sigar advertizes itself as a "portable interface for gathering system information" including network interface detection, configuration info and metrics. Take a look at its NetInterfaceStat class.

Note that Sigar also relies on platform specific JNIs, i.e. Rob H's remark still applies.